# indexeddb: how to get request result and cursor value

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

Two questions about indexeddb operations.

1. what is the reliable way to get result from an idb request. I see two froms

`var cursor = request.result;` [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#cursor-concept)

`var cursor = event.target.result;` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBCursor)

would they give same results always for all requests.

2.
 is there a `value` property on cursor retuned by `index.openCursor`. I see it is used in W3C spec at one place, in a example.

```
[report(cursor.value.isbn, cursor.value.title, cursor.value.author);][3]
```

is there a place it say I can use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) In general it's all requests that have results. There are different types of requests (such as `IDBOpenDBRequest` and cursor requests) and various ways to get to objects such as `IDBDatabase` and `IDBObjectStore` depending on the request. `event.target.result` is just one example.

For example:
* An `IDBIndex` will have an `IDBObjectStore` at `objectStore`.
* With an `IDBObjectStore` you'll find a reference to an `IDBTransaction` at `transaction`
* On an `IDBTransaction`, there will be a `db` attribute with an `IDBDatabase`.
* An `IDBOpenDBRequest` will have its `IDBDatabase` on the `result` property

In addition to `event.target` you'll also find an `event.source` that carries such objects and references.

Various types of IDB objects can appear as a `target`, and so the `event.target.result` will change depending on the method used. It even depends on the callback used: a `success` callback from a cursor request yields an `IDBCursorWithValue` as `event.target.result` (with a request being the target) and nothing on a `complete` event.

2) In general it's just `IDBCursorWithValue` requests that have a `value`. There are various requests that don't yield value, which even include certain types of valueless cursor requests.

*Update*: A `IDBRequest` will have a `IDBCursorWithValue` at `request.result` and its cursor value is usually (but not always) going to be at `request.result.value` (with the exception being value-free cursors, which I doubt you'll be using). `request` is returned by the method synchronously (my preferred method to grab a reference) or obtained via `event.target` (a little confusing). Check out this [method called `standardCursor` in my library](https://github.com/editor/dash/blob/2e03fc503e89e0d2534fcee7e8f22100072a05c2/lib/dash.dev.js#L280). It's reused by `entries.delete`, `entries.get` and `entries.update` and should point you in the right direction. My lib is literate and implemented to spec w/exception of its `webkitGetDatabaseNames` support.

Comment: +1 thanks. can you help me to navigate through the spec for `openCursor`. so for that operation, how to get the cursor. spec says, `this method creates a cursor. The cursor must implement the IDBCursorWithValue interface`. but, where can I see the cursor will be at `event.target.result`, or at `requ`est.result`. I am almost there :-)

Comment: Glad you're working through it. It's a rewarding API once you have. Updated my answer.

Comment: thanks again. I wish I had seen your library, as I did almost same thing, a promise based wrapper. I will evaluate `dashdb` further as I am sure it is more polished. thanks again.

Comment: My library is well tested and should be usable today. But I'm working on the Web Worker and developer API. I'll have my library fully ready by end of May. I'd love your feedback and help. [Follow me on Twitter](http://twitter.com/taylorbuley) for more IDB info - there's actually quite a few of us IDB folks hanging around.

Comment: I am not sure I am looking at the right place, but in the doc, I don't see where to give the configuration needed for `onupgradeneeded` cb. For example, I create all stores and `createIndex` for each. in `dashdb` can I set the indexes so I can query on them.

Comment: Are you talking about my library or IDB in general? Either way open up a question and I'd be happy to help get to the bottom of it. (You don't have to create indexes or stores or databases in dash, just try to use them and they'll be there. Can explain in an answer)

Comment: my docs are out of date. so really briefly, here's an example that will create a db, store and index you declare, then add data, then use that index to get the data back https://gist.github.com/editor/a03d9e7981bbf207f23e http://jsfiddle.net/FTZeA/5/